# Get complete ddl for index in oracle

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, dbms-metadata

I am using oracle 11g/12c. I want to get ddl of indexes in my database. For this I used the query -

```
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('INDEX','SYS_IL0000091971C00001$$','CCEEXPERTS') FROM dual
```

Here 'SYS_IL0000091971C00001$$' is my index name and 'CCEEXPERTS' is my owner name.

From this I get the ddl -

```
 CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "CCEEXPERTS"."SYS_IL0000091971C00001$$" ON "CCEEXPERTS"."DATABLOB" (
```

And my actual ddl is -

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "CCEEXPERTS"."SYS_IL0000091971C00001$$" ON "CCEEXPERTS"."DATABLOB" (
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" 
  PARALLEL (DEGREE 0 INSTANCES 0) ;
```

In actual ddl after "CCEEXPERTS"."DATABLOB" ( , next line character and from their the ddl is truncted.

How can I get the complete ddl? Please help me...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what this have to do with tsql?

Comment: It is suspect that you can't see things after newline. This is your problem. How are you running your query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQLplus, set these before running the procedure.

```
set long 100000
set longchunksize 100000
```

Comment: I think that should be *longchunksize*.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has a [DBMS_METADATA](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_metada.htm#ARPLS026) package to retrieve and customize the DDL returned.  Default settings for all indexes SQL:

```
select DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('INDEX', index_name) 
from all_indexes 
where owner in (USER, 'USER_OTHER_THAN_LOGGED_IN_USER');
```

A pl/sql block example:

```
set serveroutput on 
DECLARE
   V_DDL CLOB;
BEGIN
   DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM(DBMS_METADATA.SESSION_TRANSFORM,'STORAGE',false);
   DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM(DBMS_METADATA.SESSION_TRANSFORM, 'PRETTY', true);
   dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(dbms_metadata.session_transform,'TABLESPACE',false);
   V_DDL := DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('VIEW', 'A_VIEW_NAME');
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_DDL);
END;
```