# ORA-00922: missing or invalid option when execute "set long 100000" statement in oracle

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am developing a java sample in which I execute query one after other to get ddl of indexces.My java code is -

```
Statement stmt2 = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs2 =null;                             
String query = "set long 100000";
rs2 =stmt2.execute(query);
query = "set longchucksize 100000";
rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery(query);
query = "SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('INDEX','SYS_IL0000091971C00001$$','CCEEXPERTS') FROM dual";
rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery(queryForScript);
```

when the following statement run it throws **ORA-00922: missing or invalid option** exception

> String query = "set long 100000";
>
> rs2 =stmt2.execute(query);

How I execute these statement?

Comment: But if I am not setting this, then it returns incomplete ddl as in link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42152677/get-complete-ddl-for-index-in-oracle

Answer (score 1):

`Set long 10000` is a SQL*PLUS command, not a standard SQL that's why you hit the error.

### Example

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE','YOUR_OBJECTS','JAY') as ddl FROM dual");

              while(rs.next()){
                  System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
              }
```

### Output

```
CREATE TABLE "JAY"."YOUR_OBJECTS" 
   (    "OWNER" VARCHAR2(128) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "OBJECT_NAME" VARCHAR2(128) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "SUBOBJECT_NAME" VARCHAR2(128), 
    "OBJECT_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "DATA_OBJECT_ID" NUMBER, 
    "OBJECT_TYPE" VARCHAR2(23), 
    "CREATED" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "LAST_DDL_TIME" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "TIMESTAMP" VARCHAR2(19), 
    "STATUS" VARCHAR2(7), 
    "TEMPORARY" VARCHAR2(1), 
    "GENERATED" VARCHAR2(1), 
    "SECONDARY" VARCHAR2(1), 
    "NAMESPACE" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "EDITION_NAME" VARCHAR2(128), 
    "SHARING" VARCHAR2(13), 
    "EDITIONABLE" VARCHAR2(1), 
    "ORACLE_MAINTAINED" VARCHAR2(1)
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ORAPDB1_TBS1"
```

I got partial DDL while running the same statement on SQL*PLUS.

```
SQL> SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('INDEX','SYS_IL0000092981C00086$$','JAY') as ddl FROM dual;

DDL
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "JAY"."SYS_IL0000092981C00086$$" ON "JAY"."SYS_EXPORT_SCH
```

Here I can obtain whole DDL by setting `SET LONG` BUT I get complete output on Java Application.

### Output(Eclipse)

```
  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "JAY"."SYS_IL0000092981C00086$$" ON "JAY"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01" (
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ORAPDB1_TBS1" 
  PARALLEL (DEGREE 0 INSTANCES 0)
```

Comment: I am getting table ddl absolutly correct but the index ddl is not correct