# ORA-00922: missing or invalid option when execute “set long 100000” statement of oracle using java code

Tags: java, oracle11g

I am creating sample code using java form which first executing query "set long 100000" and after immediate executing get_ddl query for getting schema of index using batch operation.

My sample code are:-

```
     Statement stmt2 = con.createStatement();
       ResultSet rs2 =null;                             
       String query = "set long 100000";
       stmt2.addBatch(query);
       query = "set longchuncksize 100000";
       stmt2.addBatch(query);          
       int[] i=stmt2.executeBatch();
       queryForScript = "SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('INDEX','INDEX_NAME','SCHEMA_NAME') FROM dual";

        rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery(queryForScript);
```

When i execute code it throws following error :-

**ORA-00922: missing or invalid option exception**

Please suggest how can i execute query using batch operation in java.

I have also refer following post [ORA-00922: missing or invalid option when execute “set long 100000” statement in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42155372/ora-00922-missing-or-invalid-option-when-execute-set-long-100000-statement-in)

Comment: `"set long 100000"` reduce the size to `"set long 10000"` and try. This is just a guess

Comment: `SET` is a SQL*Plus command. I don't know Java, but - if you ask me - I'd say that it won't work here.